# How to convert the currency AED to USD then pass it to Paypal

Tags: php, paypal, currency, paypal-ipn

Can anyone provide me a solution .How to convert the currency AED to USD before pass it to Paypal .

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use Google

Try

```
var_dump(simpleConvert("AED","USD",1));
```

Output

```
array
  '1.000000' => string '0.272257' (length=8)
```

Function Used

```
function simpleConvert($from,$to,$amount)
{
    $content = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a='.$amount.'&from='.$from.'&to='.$to);

     $doc = new DOMDocument;
     @$doc->loadHTML($content);
     $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

     $result = $xpath->query('//*[@id="currency_converter_result"]/span')->item(0)->nodeValue;
     return $result;
}
```

Comment: Apparantly, the URL has changed from `https://www.google.com` to `https://finance.google.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple add this code.

```
<?php

function convertCurrency($amount, $from, $to){
$data = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/finance/converter?   a=$amount&from=$from&to=$to");
preg_match("/<span class=bld>(.*)<\/span>/",$data, $converted);
$converted = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $converted[1]);
return number_format(round($converted, 3),2);
}
echo convertCurrency("10", "AED", "USD");

?>
```